# Índice para MYSQL - ORDER BY influência na hora de criar um índice?

Tags: mysql, otimização, índices

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT type,name,points FROM clients WHERE type='1' ORDER BY name
```

Eu criei um índice para a tabela "clients" somente em cima do campo "type".
O fato de acrescentar um ORDER BY em cima de um campo não indexado, irá afectar o tempo de resposta da query?

Comment: O seu campo ID não é chave primária?

Comment: É o que o @Bacco disse. Para ver quais índices são usados de fato, execute `EXPLAIN SELECT points FROM clients WHERE type='1' ORDER BY id`.

Comment: @Bacco o índice id existe na tabela, o que eu queria entender é se na query acima faz diferença ter o ID como índice pelo fato de utilizar ORDER BY ID na query.

Comment: @bfavaretto  o índice id existe na tabela, o que eu queria entender é se na query acima faz diferença ter o ID como índice pelo fato de utilizar ORDER BY ID na query.

Comment: @Bacco não me expliquei bem, alterei a pergunta e penso que agora está bem mais clara. Utilizar o id não foi um bom exemplo, alterei o exemplo também.

Comment: Primeiro um índice em campo como type provavelmente não será usado pois será um campo com poucos valores diferentes (baixa cardinalidade) , o otimizador optará por full table scan, o ORDER BY todavia tem um tempo computacional e dependendo do índice e das colunas poderá ser usado.

Comment: Nota, leia sobre índices bitmap do Oracle para esta questão da cardinalidade. Questão de uso de índices ou não depende de muitos fatores além da existência do mesmo e de seu uso no WHERE.

Answer (score 2):

Sim. Observe o que diz o [manual de referência](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/pt/order-by-optimization.html):

> Se você quiser ter uma velocidade ORDER BY maior, primeiro você deve
>   ver se você pode fazer que o MySQL use índices...

Mas a questão pratica é o quão relevante é esse tempo? Essa resposta só pode ser dada com a análise de otimização de suas consultas.

Neste manual, encontrará toda a referência que precisa para fazer esta análise: [Otimizando selects e Outras Consultas](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/pt/query-speed.html).

Comment: Já removi, obrigado